# which table structure would be better?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, relational-database

I cant decide which way is better to create a **key/value** **Tag** model in **Django**,

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    is_key = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, related_name="key")
```

or

```
class TagKey(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)    

class TagValue(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    port = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    key = models.ForeignKey(TagKey)
```

All I intent to do is create a key:value based tag model which I can use to tag my applications.

Explanation: What I am doing in **Tag** class is that I am giving a self relation to itself when I will be adding a value tag, but if I am adding a key type Tag then I wont be populating the **parent** field. 
P.S I have to use my own tag model so please don't suggest third party **Django** tag app

Comment: You should remove the redundant field. It's a bit redundant to read question with that. (e.g. `created_at`, `modified_at`, etc...)

Comment: This is strange looking data structure.  `Tag` is to defined recursively. `TagKey` & `TagValue` is defined 1:m.  What's your use case? To determine which is better, it is depends on your use case...

Comment: @Yeo I am not sure what you mean but I edited the question. may be that will clear it up a little bit.